# TFS Effort not displaying if state is 'Done"

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem

We have some work items (PBI, Bug) in TFS with a status of 'Done' and the Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort will not display if the value is not set. If there is a value the field displays and is read only.  The read only behavior I understand, It is set in the workflow state :

```
<WORKFLOW>
  <STATES>
    <STATE value="Done">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort">
          <READONLY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
```

However I am not understanding why the field does not display if there is no value. Is there an option to display this field regardless of the presence of a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not specifically just the control associated with the *Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort* field that has the *hide* behaviour you describe. 
All fields that are marked as **readonly** in the *Done* state rules (in the work item workflow) behave this way.

If you are dead-set on always showing this field you can remove the readonly rule for the field in the workflow tab as shown in the screen below at the expense of losing the **readonly** functionality itself.

Note: Screenshots taken from [TFS 2015 PowerTools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) VS extension's process editor.

[image: readonly rule in in workflow state]

However,

---

**Consider potential alternatives though; like predefined effort values.**

Our production TFS instance has **allowed** and **suggested** value **field rules** for effort instead.

We use the fibonacci series typically printed on planning poker cards as *allowed* and *suggested* values with a default *opening* value of 100 (ubiquitously understood to imply that a PBI has not been estimated or cannot be estimated if playing stock planning poker).

For reference, here is a basic idea of what we have done:

**Default value:** 100

**Suggested and Allowed:** 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20, 40, 100

**When:** (State changes to committed) 0 and 100 not allowed.

[image]

**Insight 1: What this approach gives us in reference to your question:**

1. Effort always has a value hence; the ui control is always visible.
2. We do not lose the read-only behaviour.

**Insight 2: What this gives us outside of the scope of your question:**

1. We always get an effort value which is valuable for estimation reasons.

**Note:** [A related question was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295946/how-to-readonly-of-the-tfs-work-item-field-but-not-hidden?rq=1)